# Show Page Loading Spinner in Google Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code and I would like to know where to place the code to show the Spinner image every time a Dynamic Post is clicked or when you navigate back to the main List Page:

```
function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/");
    feed.setNumEntries(8);
    feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT);
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById("feed");
            var posts = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

                    posts += '<li>';
                    posts += '<a href="#articlepost" onclick="showPost(' + id + ')">';
                    posts += '<div class="ui-li-heading">' + entry.title + '</div>' ;
                    posts += '<div class="ui-li-desc">' + n_date + '</div>';
                    posts += '</a>';
                    posts += '</li>';   
                }
            posts += '</ul>';
        // Append each list of posts to #devotionlist in html page 
        $("#devotionlist").append(posts);
        //$("#devotionlist").listview('refresh');
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

I have tried some codes seen but none works for me...

Comment: anyone with idea or should I rewrite my code using $.ajax in this sample:

    $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner

Answer (score 0):

OK I did figure this out the simplest way. I added the following code in the Function that calls and displays each clicked Posts:

```
function showPost(id) {
    $('#articlecontent').html('<div id="ui_loader"><img src="css/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax_loader"/></div>');
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var output='';
        output += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        output += data.post.content;
        $('#articlecontent').html(output);
```

with the following CSS:

```
#ui_loader {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
 }

.ajax_loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px; /* -1 * image width / 2 */
    margin-top: -32px;  /* -1 * image height / 2 */
    display: block;     
}
```

Note: I took out the opacity from the CSS since the Loader was looking too dark and too white when I increase or decrease the opacity settings, so what I did was to generate a new Loader with transparent background from [AJAX Loader Site](http://www.ajaxload.info/)